# How postgres process a query on a view with fake values for some columns?

Tags: postgresql, view

3 Tables and 1 View
How will query work with fake "null as col" values?

```
Table1
- IndexedCol1 
- Col2
- CommonIndexedCol1
- CommonIndexedCol2
- CommonIndexedCol3

Table2
- IndexedCol2 
- Col3
- Col4
- CommonIndexedCol1
- CommonIndexedCol2
- CommonIndexedCol3

Table3
- IndexedCol3 
- Col5
- Col6
- CommonIndexedCol1
- CommonIndexedCol2
- CommonIndexedCol3


View1
- Table1.IndexedCol1
- Table2.IndexedCol2
- Table3.IndexedCol3
- CommonIndexedCol1
- CommonIndexedCol2
- CommonIndexedCol3
```

View1 Query is:

```
SELECT IndexedCol1, null as IndexedCol2, null as IndexedCol3, CommonIndexedCol1, CommonIndexedCol2, CommonIndexedCol3 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT null as IndexedCol1, IndexedCol2, null as IndexedCol3, CommonIndexedCol1, CommonIndexedCol2, CommonIndexedCol3 FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT null as IndexedCol1, null as IndexedCol2, IndexedCol3, CommonIndexedCol1, CommonIndexedCol2, CommonIndexedCol3 FROM Table3
```

**Assuming each table have 1 million row**

If I run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
```

Will postgres skip the selects that have SELECT (null as IndexedCol1) thus only querying 1 table, 1 million rows only, does it understand that this select will result in all nulls so it should skip the second and third select queries from the beginning?
Or will it query the whole 3 million records in the 3 tables for not null IndexedCol1?

Comment: PostgreSQL supports [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) to tell you how it will handle the query..

Comment: Run `explain (analyze) select ...` and you will see what Postgres will do

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, typo in the question, fixed... I'll do the `EXPLAIN` now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How postgres process a query on a view with fake values for some columns?

PostgreSQL optimizer should push down the WHERE clause from query which was made on the VIEW to the VIEW query definition.

With other words VIEW processing/handling optimizing on PostgreSQL works like a SQL "preprocessor" or template system.

The query

```
SELECT * 
FROM View1 
WHERE CommonIndexedCol1 = 1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
```

Would be rewritten into

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         IndexedCol1
         , null as IndexedCol2
         , null as IndexedCol3
         , CommonIndexedCol1
         , CommonIndexedCol2
         , CommonIndexedCol3
     FROM 
         Table1
     WHERE 
         CommonIndexedCol1 = 1 AND IndexedCol1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT
      null as IndexedCol1
    , IndexedCol2
    , null as IndexedCol3
    , CommonIndexedCol1, CommonIndexedCol2, CommonIndexedCol3
   FROM Table2
   WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
   UNION
    SELECT
       null as IndexedCol1
     , null as IndexedCol2
     , IndexedCol3
     , CommonIndexedCol1
     , CommonIndexedCol2
     , CommonIndexedCol3
   FROM Table3
   WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
 ) AS View1
```

After more optimalisation (flatting out)

```
   SELECT
       IndexedCol1
     , null as IndexedCol2
     , null as IndexedCol3
     , CommonIndexedCol1
     , CommonIndexedCol2
     , CommonIndexedCol3
   FROM Table1
   WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT
      null as IndexedCol1
    , IndexedCol2
    , null as IndexedCol3
    , CommonIndexedCol1, CommonIndexedCol2, CommonIndexedCol3
   FROM Table2
   WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
   UNION
    SELECT
       null as IndexedCol1
     , null as IndexedCol2
     , IndexedCol3
     , CommonIndexedCol1
     , CommonIndexedCol2
     , CommonIndexedCol3
   FROM Table3
   WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
```

If you would run

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE CommonIndexedCol1=1 AND IndexedCol1 is NOT NULL
```

You should see Table1, Table2 and Table3 and not a single mention of View1 in the explain..